# Is it a phrasal verb with "in"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm a bit confused with the sentences below:

> 1. I know you're **in** there
> 2. What was the point of sending us **in** there
> 3. She'd been **in** there all afternoon

I sense they're clear for me, but I don't know whether to relate that **in** to the verbs or associate it with **there** thinking of just **in there**?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! Please take some of your time to visit [the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I know you're **in** there. (in = inside)
> 2. What was the point of sending us **in** there (in = into, towards)
> 3. She'd been **in** there all afternoon (in = inside)

The preposition **in** relates to the adverb of place **there** in all three cases, so there are no phrasal verbs with **in** in any of the sentences.

There indeed exists a phrasal verb **[to send in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/send-in)**, and had the word **there** been absent in sentence 2, we could've said it contained it:

> What was the point of **sending** us **in**?

Answer (score 2):

"in there" is short for "in that house/room/place/box there". You can choose any other noun that fits. The noun is dropped because from the situation it is clear what the speaker means.

Comment: A nice explanation, easier to understand than my jargon-filled one. (0: